# How to perform the equivalent of Excel rolling sumifs in dplyr?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, dplyr

In the below reproducible code, I would like to add a column for SumIfs using dplyr as detailed in the below image, whereby the Excel `sumifs()` formula in column H of the image has conditions with the tops of the specified ranges "anchored", for a "rolling" calculation as you move down row-wise. Any recommendations for how to do the same in dplyr? I'm sure it requires grouping but unsure of how to handle conditions. The blue below shows the current reproducible code output, the yellow shows what I would like to add, and the non-highlighted shows the underlying XLS formulas.

Now using my words: to derive Sumifs, for each row one-at-a-time rolling from top-to-bottom of the array sequentially, sum all values in column D from the top of the column D range to the current row in the Column D range that have a column C "Code1" value less than the current row column C "Code1" value. So for example in deriving the value of 3 in cell G6: add the 1 in cell D3 (because its Code1 of 0 (cell C3) is < Code1 of 3 (cell C6)) to the 2 in cell D5 (because its Code1 of 1 (cell C5) is < Code1 of 3 (cell C6)).

[image]

Reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)

myData <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("B","R","R","R","R","B","A","A","A"),
    Group = c(0,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0),
    Code1 = c(0,1,1,3,3,4,-1,0,0),
    Code2 = c(1,0,2,0,1,2,1,0,0)
  )

CountIfs <- function(x,y) {
  out <- integer(length(x))
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    cond1 <- y[1:i] > 0
    cond2 <- x[1:i] == x[i] 
    out[i] <- sum(cond1*cond2)
  }
  out
}

myDataRender <- 
  myData %>% 
  mutate(CountIfs = CountIfs(Code1, Code2))
print.data.frame(myDataRender)
```

**Adapt Tsai solution for situations where the top/bottom of the XLS `sumifs()` ranges are anchored (fixed, not rolling)**(where first XLS formula in the image would be `=SUMIFS(D$3:D$11,C$3:$C11,"<"&C3)`), for those of us transitioning from XLS to R:

```
myData %>% mutate(SumIfs = sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Code2[1:n()][Code1[1:n()] < Code1[x]])))
```

Comment: As a note, the challenge with this type of thing in R and `dplyr` is that it views the entire column as a vector. So the trick to this type of problem is how do you access both the individual element for each row and the entire column vector at the same time? The typical way is to iterate through the vector using something like the `map_*()` family from `purrr`, or the `sapply()` or `Map()` functions in base. That way you can loop through each element of a vector, while also accessing the entire vector itself.

Comment: If  the top/bottom of the XLS sumifs() ranges are anchored , `[1:n()]` could be removed, i.e. `sum(Code2[Code1 < Code1[x]])`

Comment: Thanks Darren! Is it possible to switch the `CountIfs()` for-loop function used in the OP into the same sort of slick, condensed, understandable `sapply()` used for SumIfs in your base solution? I've been fiddling with that but no luck yet.

Comment: @Village.Idyot `myData %>% mutate(CountIfs = sapply(1:n(), \(x) sum(Code2[1:x] > 0 & Code1[1:x] == Code1[x])))`

Comment: Hi Darren, if you have a moment, could you please take a quick peek at my follow-on post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73455632/how-to-perform-the-equivalent-of-excel-minifs-in-r-dplyr? The last thing I'm trying to figure out in XLS/dplyr equivalence are conditional min/max functions. Something I also do in XLS, both for fixed arrays and rolling arrays row-by-row. I like the clear logic your `sapply()` solution for XLS `sumifs()` but I'm having a hard time figuring out something as clean for `minifs()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `map()` or `imap()` from `purrr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# (1)
myData %>%
  mutate(SumIfs = map_dbl(1:n(), ~ sum(Code2[1:.x][Code1[1:.x] < Code1[.x]])))

# (2)
myData %>%
  mutate(SumIfs = imap_dbl(Code1, ~ sum(Code2[1:.y][Code1[1:.y] < .x])))
```

```
#   Name Group Code1 Code2 SumIfs
# 1    B     0     0     1      0
# 2    R     1     1     0      1
# 3    R     1     1     2      1
# 4    R     2     3     0      3
# 5    R     2     3     1      3
# 6    B     0     4     2      4
# 7    A     0    -1     1      0
# 8    A     0     0     0      1
# 9    A     0     0     0      1
```

---

If you don't want to rely on `purrr`, the `map()` solution can be adapted directly for the base `sapply()` version:

```r
myData %>%
  mutate(SumIfs = sapply(1:n(), \(x) sum(Code2[1:x][Code1[1:x] < Code1[x]])))
```

Comment: `.x` is `myData` in that case?

Comment: @Julian `.x` is each of `1:n()` for the `map()` case and each of `Code1` in the `imap()` case.

Comment: I amended the OP to include a slightly modified base `sapply()` solution for those cases where the array range to sum and corresponding conditions are fixed (tops and bottoms of ranges are anchored), rather than rolling. Both are common in XLS formulas so both R solutions are now presented here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way using `map2_dbl()` with the row number.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

myData %>% 
  mutate(SumIfs = map2_dbl(Code1, row_number(),
                           ~ sum(if_else(Code1 < .x & row_number() <= .y, Code2, 0))))
```

Also using base `Map()`, this will scale to as many criteria as you want.

```r
library(dplyr)

myData %>% 
  mutate(SumIfs = unlist(Map(\(x, y) sum(if_else(Code1 < x & row_number() <= y, Code2, 0)),
                                         Code1, row_number())))
```

Comment: Hi Adam, when I run your base (second) version, I get an error that says '\' is an unexpected token. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Village.Idyot you have an older version of R. The `\()` is a shortcut for `function()` when used like this, added in version 4.1 I think. Replace it with the word function, `\(x, y)` = `function(x, y)` and it should work. Same goes for the other solution where you had the same problem.

Comment: OK thanks I've been afraid to update R because of the risk that it messes up some of my previous work. Now is not a good time for me to deal with debugging old code that used to work but no longer works because of an update. I'll research what risks an update entails.

Comment: @Village.Idyot no need to update then. Just make that slight modification and move on with it until you have more time.